# Wallet of ERC20 token

Tags: wallets

okay so i am making a mobile application where i want to place  the ERC20 wallet with that application ? so my question is :

1. is it possible to do this ?
2. how much will it be secure ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes. You simply need ABI for ERC20 tokens and their addresses. After you get everything you need just initiate contract instance like below on your js side:

---

```
var MyContract = web3.eth.contract(abiArray);

// instantiate by address
var contractInstance = MyContract.at(address);
```

---

2. It’s safe as long as token contract is standard ERC20 token.

---

Note that to have all the functionality to manage token balance you don’t need any additional contracts or any specific external wallet, you simply use standard ethereum account. Security question arise when you decide to build your own wallet which will add some extra functionality to already existing.

Answer (score 0):

ERC20 tokens are used exclusively on the Ethereum platform. The term ERC20 stands for “Ethereum Request For Comments” and 20 is an unique ID number that is used to distinguish the token standard from other tokens. The ERC20 tokens follow a list of rules and regulations on the Ethereum platform. An ERC20 compliant token or smart contract brings certain benefits to its users.